# How to add any jar file in the Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working the basic android application , I do not know where to add the jar file in the android studio.

Comment: If that .jar file is any api you want to use in your project then copy it in `yourProject/app/libs` directory

Comment: i add the jar in the libs folder but it's not taking

Comment: also add `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` under `dependencies {...}` in `gradle.build`

Comment: Error:(7, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes: The project 'App' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings.The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: You are adding in wrong `gradle.build` remove it from `gradle.build(Project:projectName)` and add in `gradle.build(Module:app)` see my answer

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

Comment: This is my post. You may find it useful. I tried to explain 3 different approaches for importing JAR files into Android studio step by step by screenshots. Please visit this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35345492/5475941][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35345492/5475941

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can add the jar file in the android studio as follows:

1. Add a folder in your project named "Libs" and keep the jar files inside this folder , which you want to use in your project.
2. In the "Project->Project" view, You will be able to see the jar file from android studio (you may not see it in the "Project->android" view). Right click on the jar file and select the option "Add as Library" and Click Ok.

Comment: First you have to click the top drop-down menu "Android" and choose "Project" to see the folders.

Comment: There is no "Add as Library". I am using 2.2.3.

Answer (score 24):

First copy the `.jar` file in `yourproject/app/libs` directory

Then open your **gradle.build(Module:app)** and copy `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` in `dependencies{}`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android...."
        minSdkVersion 9
        ....
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') <--- here
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

After this select: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: I've tried this and still no go. Noticed `libs` doesn't show up in my project tree, even though it is definitely in the file system.

Comment: @trans it happens if Android Studio can't refresh your project tree. Collapse project directory and reopen in project tree, it should show your libs dir or restart Android Studio.